# Need to download thousands of items from iCloud Photos

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, photos.app

I need to download >10,000 photos/videos from iCloud Photos.

The web interface only allows 1,000 at a time. I went ahead and did that, generating a bunch of ZIP files, but several of them are corrupt, and it took hours.

Is there no other way to batch download them all?

All I found was https://privacy.apple.com/account -- which allows to request a download (as ZIPs, and which takes days); or transfer to Google Photos (which also takes days); but I would like a local copy (for various reasons.)

I wish `rclone` supported iCloud.

Comment: You could export from the Photos app on the Mac. Unlike icloud.com you’re not limited to 1,000 items at a time. Though it did take several days for me to export ~20,000 photos…. https://support.apple.com/guide/photos/download-photos-to-your-mac-from-icloud-phtfa50fd1ec/mac

Comment: I always back up to a separate location anyway - this is updated each time I put something on the cloud...